# Jquery using map to sum array

Tags: jquery, html

My values array is returning correctly in the form of [100,200,300,500] I just wish to sum up these values, what am I doing wrong?

### Jquery

```
$('select').focus(function () {
    previous = parseInt($(this).val());
}).change(function() {

    var item_cost = parseInt($(this).attr('cost'));
    
    values = $.map($('select[name="cookies"]'), function (e) {
            
        return $(e).val()* item_cost;
                     
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(values[i]);
            console.log(total);                              
        }
    });

    alert(values);
```

Comment: Dunno, what are you seeing in the console? Please fix your code, it's hard to read as-is.

Comment: nothing, it seems the for loop is never being executed.

Comment: You have a return statement in the first line of your `map` callback function, before the for loop

Comment: `return` statement must be in the end of function if you ofcourse don`t want to exit function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs formatting. You missed a closing `});` You need to declare `var total = 0;` as well. I'm not sure if that is elsewhere in your code.

```
$('select').focus(function() {
    previous = parseInt($(this).val());
}).change(function() {
    var item_cost = parseInt($(this).attr('cost'));

    values = $.map($('select[name="cookies"]'), function(e) {
        return $(e).val() * item_cost;
    }); // <-- RIGHT THERE

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt(values[i]);
        console.log(total);
    }
});
alert(values);​
```